# How can I force Steam to download DLC?

Tags: steam

I just bought some DLC for *Train Simulator*, but after completing the purchase I skipped to another page without starting the download.

Now the DLC shows up in my list of DLC as "not installed" (in Dutch, so I don't know what the exact English wording is), even though "install" *is* checked.

Unchecking and rechecking "install" didn't do it either.

**How do I get Steam to download and install it?**

Comment: Steam should automatically start downloading DLC the second you purchase it. I've never experienced any situation where the game didn't download the DLC once I purchased it.

Comment: @KABoissonneault , nope, checked. Updated the question.

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, feel free to post it as an answer, and even accept it (once the two day time limit passes). We encourage self-answers here, as long as they are good quality and not duplicates.

Comment: I think the DLC will also be forced to load the next time you start the game but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the game you're after to open properties, click on the "Local Files" tab, click on "Verify Integrity of Game Files" let it do its thing. Once complete if should say it's missing some files (your DLC) and it'll go off and download them.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue in the past. There is no guaranteed way to trigger the download. Sometimes it will even launch the game without downloading the DLC first. What mostly helps, is to quit Steam completely and then start it up again.

Sometimes also unchecking the "install" check box and checking it again helps.

Comment: This is the process I had to use with Fallout 4 with every DLC release. I was a season pass holder so I wanted to play each one the day it came out.  It's rather tedious but I couldn't find a better solution at the time.

Answer (score 0):

DLC will normally not download if you are running a Steam game already - especially if it uses Steam Cloud Save sync.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a dual boot Win 10 and Linux Laptop and noticed that once the DLC downloaded on my Win 10, it will not download on my Linux.

The strange thing is that it was showing that the DLC was installed.

Right Clicking the game and choosing properties, under the DLC tab I unticked the Install checkbox, then ticked it again. This seemed to force installing the DLC.